# Any Security Risk of Using MongoDB ID vs a Counter in URL?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, security

UPDATE: Moved post to security: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120952/security-risks-of-using-mongodb-id-vs-a-counter-in-url/

In my Angular app, I use the MongoDB id in the URLs to show various data/in the links.

Is there any security risk to this or should i use a counter, then in my DB have some sort of collection that links this counter to the actual ID:

So instead of:

```
mysite.com/story/56ede7fsdfdsfdsfs2a7283
```

use

```
mysite.com/story/32
```

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. Is the data related to this ID private or should it be restricted to some users? Is your DB encrypted? How are this IDs generated?

Comment: No its not really private - open to all users (registered or not). DB is not encrypted atm but will be. And the IDs themselves are what MongoDB generates.

Comment: If your DB is going to be encrypted I won't be giving [ObjectIDs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) to possible hackers. Even less cause all ObjectIDs will have similar values (Same machine identifier and probably same process id). Anyway you should be better asking this in the [security stack exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, you say its not ok?

Comment: Exactly, I think it's not ok to give hackers the ObjectIDs of the MongoDB objects you want to encrypt.

Comment: Think it this way. ObjectIDs generated by Mongo, are essentially built as timestamp+machine-id+process-id+counter. As the last part is a counter, hackers can forge valid ObjectIDs from a given one (Just substract 1 from the previous ID). With this information a possible hacker can obtain a lot of information from your DB, which will be encrypted. Knowing existing data from an encrypted DB reduces it's security significantly. I don't know exactly how much this IDs will help hackers to crack your DB, but why taking unnecessary risks?

Comment: Makes sense - So the way around this I see is to add a new field `publicID` in the document. Is this an acceptable way?

Comment: What I would do is use the ObjectID, but encrypted with a different key than the DB (A `publicID` in the DB would have the same problem). But anyway, for better answers (I'm not an expert), please ask in the [security stack exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Mr.E: your points are moot. Integer ids are much easier to increment/forge than object ids. If data is publicly accessible, it doesn't matter, which type of id it is. If some data needs to be protected, it should be done by means other than hoping that attacker doesn't know the ids of "secret" pages. This means proper authorization, etc. The only drawback of object ids is that they're longer (harder for humans to memorize/compare, etc.). In terms of security, there is no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - so the storys are all public read only. So would you say ids randomly generated either like the above URL '36721726' or youtube like IDs 'x33klje2' would be fine?

Comment: @userMod2: yep, no difference security-wise.

Comment: But i guess for 'human memory kindness' something shorter, easier to remember (but still random to some degree) should be ok?

Comment: @userMod2: yes, short integers are more friendly to humans. However, is this a factor? Does your app rely on humans _memoriziing_ and _recollecting_ urls rather than, say, bookmarking or googling them up?

Comment: @userMod2: the url shorteners, for example (bit.ly and the company): they're not built to help humans remember urls, they're built to help machines: transform arbitrary length urls into (almost) constant length urls, so that you can tweet them or something.

Comment: Nope it doesn't - hhhmmm - makes me think. I guess the only reason i wanted shorted IDs in URL is because i also append the title of the story to the end e.g. `mysite.com/story/82edjwdhfdsnjfksdfnsdfosd89/asia-stocks-rise`. Maybe i should just leave long as no ones really remembering that